# sklearn preprocessing.scale() function , when to use it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

i'm building a neural network using `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` :

```
   clf =  sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes= (11,11,11),max_iter = 500)
```

before training it, I'm creating a new fetchers from existing ones using the

```
preprocessing.scale()
```

like so:

```
labels = someDataBase.loadLabels()
fetchers = someDataBase.loadFetchers()
fetchers = preprocessing.scale(fetchers)
```

and from them,  using  the `train_test_split` function, creating the test an train values, like so:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(fetchers,labels,test_size = 0.2)
```

then I feed it to the fit function of  the MLPClassifier

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

now that I have a trained neural network

I wanna used it to predict base on a new fetchers
using the predict method of the MLPClassifier
this fetchers are not the test one, the are total new values

should I be using the preprocessing.scale() again? 
and then feeding them into the predict method?
or just used them as they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уour method may give different scaling factors. It is for single scaling jobs, but not for the ones requiring consistent transformation.

I suggest you rather use `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`. It is quite well documented and has examples [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).
Call `fit_transform` method when training, and just `transform` when predicting.